# Did an Ubuntu update uninstall netplan and mask networkd?

Tags: networking, server, netplan, systemd-networkd

On my Ubutntu 18.04 LTS server (with desktop added later), I was using `netplan` and `networkd` (tried to switch back to `ifup` a couple of months ago but figured I better get used to netplan).

Strangely, though, `netplan` now suddenly disappeared (was apparently uninstalled) and `systemd-networkd` suddenly became masked and I have no idea how this is possible and why it happened. The only thing I did was install some apparently routine updates when the update manager prompted me, but why would an update mess with my network settings?

Some more details:

I'm running a virtual machine (KVM) over a network bridge and that machine suddenly lost its network connection. That's when I realized that `netplan` was no longer running:

```
$ netplan

Command 'netplan' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install netplan.io
sudo apt install netplan
```

And:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart system-networkd
Failed to restart system-networkd.service: Unit system-networkd.service not found.
```

So I went ahead and did

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall netplan.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnetplan0 python3-netifaces
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnetplan0 netplan.io python3-netifaces
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 106 kB of archives.
After this operation, 438 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnetplan0 amd64 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3 [22.6 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-netifaces amd64 0.10.4-0.1build4 [12.8 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 netplan.io amd64 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3 [70.7 kB]
Fetched 106 kB in 0s (501 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package libnetplan0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 358917 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnetplan0_0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnetplan0:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-netifaces.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-netifaces_0.10.4-0.1build4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-netifaces (0.10.4-0.1build4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package netplan.io.
Preparing to unpack .../netplan.io_0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netplan.io (0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3) ...
Setting up python3-netifaces (0.10.4-0.1build4) ...
Setting up libnetplan0:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3) ...
Setting up netplan.io (0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
```

And then

```
$ sudo netplan try
Failed to start systemd-networkd.service: Unit systemd-networkd.service is masked.

An error occurred: Command '['systemctl', 'start', 'systemd-networkd.service']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Reverting.
Failed to start systemd-networkd.service: Unit systemd-networkd.service is masked.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/try_command.py", line 83, in command_try
    NetplanApply.command_apply(run_generate=True, sync=True, exit_on_error=False)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 179, in command_apply
    utils.systemctl_networkd('start', sync=sync, extra_services=netplan_wpa)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 86, in systemctl_networkd
    subprocess.check_call(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemctl', 'start', 'systemd-networkd.service']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/netplan", line 23, in <module>
    netplan.main()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 50, in main
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 186, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/try_command.py", line 66, in run
    self.run_command()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 186, in run_command
    self.func()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/try_command.py", line 94, in command_try
    self.revert()
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/try_command.py", line 117, in revert
    NetplanApply.command_apply(run_generate=False, sync=True, exit_on_error=False)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 179, in command_apply
    utils.systemctl_networkd('start', sync=sync, extra_services=netplan_wpa)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 86, in systemctl_networkd
    subprocess.check_call(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemctl', 'start', 'systemd-networkd.service']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I'm completely lost and have no idea what is going on. Could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: Check in `apt`'s logs (`/var/log/apt/*`) to see when and why it was removed

Comment: @muru It looks like `netplan` was already removed back in March when I tried to switch back to `ifupdown` but (thought I) didn't succeed. So I guess that means I have been using `ifupdown` over the past months and the recent updates somehow broke that setup for virtual machines (for the host, networking works fine). But according to the logs, `libvirt` was not modified during that update. What else mighty cause a previously functioning VM to loose network connectivity?

Comment: Update: as it turns out, `qemu` was indeed updated so I guess that's what broke things.